# Java - Display a text file content inside of a string

Tags: java, android

The goal is to update the "text" inside the `<string name="large_text">` without having to open and run Android Studio then updating the text to make changes inside the *scrolling activity*. I want to simply make changes to the text file and upload it to the server then it would display.

I want to display this text file inside the **large_text** `string`
https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>

   <string name="app_name">Foothillers</string>

   <string name="title_activity_scrolling">ScrollingActivity</string>

   <string name="large_text">

   Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 

Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test 

Test Test Test Test Test 

   </string>

   <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

   <string name="title_activity_news">News</string>

   <string name="title_activity_events">Events</string>

</resources>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify resource files during runtime. You can get the value using something like:

```
String someString = getResources().getString(R.string.large_text);
```

But you can't actually change the value in the resource file.

> I want to simply make changes to the text file and upload it to the server then it would display.

strings.xml is local to the application. If you want to pull data from a server and display it then don't use strings.xml (you can't), just use a database.

Comment: Thank you @Cryptic I did not know that.

Comment: Can you please give me sources or tutorials that demonstrate examples of how to add a database in my App so I could make changes to the values anytime without having to update them within Android Studio?

Comment: There are a few options. SQLite is one of them. SQLite is a database that is embedded in your application.. This basically means that you can store data on a per-app basis. This data won't be shared across all users that have your app. It will only be retained for the app that it is embedded in. If you want a set of data that can be read, updated and deleted across all of the instances of your app then you need a database running on a server. I would generally go for a cloud provider in this regard.

Comment: Here are links that sound be helpful: https://realm.io/ is an alternative to SQLite. Realm is very nice to work with. Much easier that SQLite. https://www.firebase.com/ is pretty cool. This allows for a shared set of data across all instances of your app. Amazon also has AWS S3. It's very good, however it does cost/however much storage you use, so if you're just learning it may be overkill

Comment: Thank you so very much for you answer. I will look into those options and try to see which one fits best and feel comfortable with. Again, thank you!

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!